# How can i change the path to a specific folder

Tags: php

the folder structure is like this:

plugin->upload->php->files

list->

```
'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/'.basename(__FILE__),
            //'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__).'/files/',
            //'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/files/',
            'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/',
            'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/',
```

How can i change this file  to list folder??

Comment: What does `$this->getFullUrl()` return?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want there.

Comment: http://localhost/fyp/plugin/upload/php/09185346d/11.xls

Comment: i think the it return  
localhost/fyp/plugin/upload/php/

Comment: i would like my file in localhost/fyp/list instead, thank you

Comment: localhost/fyp/plugin/upload/php/ is the where this php file locate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then make 'upload_dir' to: `dirname(__FILE__).'/../../list/'.$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: sorry but still... SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: 'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__).'/../../list/'.$_SESSION['username'],

Comment: 'upload_url' => dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/files/',

Comment: Thanks. I change it to            'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../list/'.$_SESSION['username'],
, but it gets c:// instead of localhost.., is there any way to fix it?

Comment: `__FILE__` is right, it's a magic constant of PHP. And why would you take localhost? It should be placed on your file system not on your web server

Comment: thx, because when i need to retrieve it , this should be in a internet link? so is this change to my server ip when this php file put on the server?

Comment: the full link is this , it is some problem: 
http://localhost/fyp/plugin/upload/C:/xampp/htdocs/fyp/list/09185346d/members_T_Feb_1_2012.csv

Comment: this internet link is the url :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9259/discussion-between-dan-lee-and-leo-chan)